# jQuery attr() failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

In the following code, on the line commented "PROBLEM LINE", attr causes the console.log to print out "undefined" when you click on one of the s. I can't seem to figure out why:

test.js

```
    var html = '';    
    // number of panels in the carousel
    var panelCount = 0;
    // panel that is to the forefront of the carousel
    var currentPanel = 0;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            html += '<div class="team-member" id="' + panelCount + '">' + panelCount + '</div>';
            html += '<div class="reflection" id="' + panelCount + '"></div>';
            panelCount++;
        }
        $('#carousel').html(html);


    $(".container-carousel").on('click', '.team-member', function(e) {
            var target = $(e.currentTarget);
            var targetId = parseInt(target.attr('id'));
            var frontRotation = currentPanel * (360/panelCount);

            $("#" + targetId + ".reflection").css("transform", "rotateY(   " + frontRotation + "deg ) translateZ( 288px ) translateY( 175px ) translateZ( 175px ) rotateX( 90deg )");
            var targetIdString = '' + targetId;

            /* PROBLEM LINE: */
            $("#" + currentPanel + ".reflection").attr('id', targetId);

            console.log($("#" + currentPanel + ".reflection").attr('id'));

            $("#" + targetId + ".reflection").attr('id', currentPanel);
        });




    });
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- JQuery--> 
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "test.js"></script>

<section class="container-carousel">
    <div id="carousel" style="transform: translateZ(-288px) rotateY(-360deg);"></div>
</section>

</html>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: change the `target = $(e.currentTarget);` to `target = $(this);`

Comment: You can't have IDs that start with a number.

Comment: as @StephanWeinhold said, you should prefix id with some string like `item-id` and then you can get it by using `targetId = parseInt(target.attr('id').replace(/item-/, ""));`

Comment: @StephanWeinhold you will probably retract that statement after reading this. Link is found in jQuery API selectors section also https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: @Saqueib Both `e.currentTarget` and `this` keyword refer to the same element!

Comment: @StephanWeinhold HTML5 allows that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because immediately after you change the id of the element, you try logging by selecting with the old id.

```
    $("#" + currentPanel + ".reflection").attr('id', targetId);
    /*The id is now targetId*/

    console.log($("#" + currentPanel + ".reflection").attr('id'));
    /*currentPanel will not work because an element with that id no longer exists*/
```

Change your `console.log` to

```
console.log($("#" + targetId + ".reflection").attr('id'));
```

See it working [here](http://console.log($(%22#%22%20+%20currentPanel%20+%20%22.reflection%22).attr('id'));)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is, you have duplicate IDs in your page. So the id selector will always fetch the first element with the id, the tries to apply the `.refelection` class selector which does not match thus your selector `$("#" + currentPanel + ".reflection")` does not return any result.

So use 2 different ids for the team-member and reflection elements, I think you can use a suffix as shown below for 1 element

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    html += '<div class="team-member" id="' + panelCount + '">' + panelCount + '</div>';
    html += '<div class="reflection" id="' + panelCount + '-reflection"></div>';
    panelCount++;
}
```

then

```
$("#" + targetId + "-reflection").css("transform", "rotateY(   " + frontRotation + "deg ) translateZ( 288px ) translateY( 175px ) translateZ( 175px ) rotateX( 90deg )");
```

Comment: Interesting (but probably irrelevant) note is that while [*selectors*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/#findelements) are required to return the first match, [*getElementById*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) isn't. So where support for the selectors API is lacking and *getElementById* is used instead, the element returned may not be the first with that ID. Not saying I know of a case where it isn't, just that it isn't required to be.

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.